# consume web Api using Api Token Key in Console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

[Code-Please Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysdlo.png)

I have Web Api Restful service api Key ,this key using i will get all employee Redcords from Web api service.

i will tried to consume console application but is not consumed.

URL - https://api.staging.Emp.com/api/provider/GetEmployee.

please to help me give some idea's.

Comment: The url is confidential that is why i can't mention original url.

Comment: Actually i tried for postman exe using check weather url is correct or not.url is correct reterive the records also.but using basic authuntication.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `Authorization` header with the value `Bearer <api-token>` to your request.

For example you can use this code

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.staging.Emp.com/api/provider/GetEmployee") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization,"Bearer <api-token>"); //example: "Bearer F4dfghuhgudhfgJL3"

// Get response here
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Error showing,The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: I tested the code on one of my own servers and it works. the error is involved to other things. can you tell me more details?

Comment: Actually I have to consume one third party api from my .net web api. This third party api is basic authenticated.I can able to consume this with a console application.But when i tries to consume it from  getting 401 unauthorised